# クビにします to mean "destroy"?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, song-lyrics

I'm translating a song and there's a certain part that's confusing me.

> もしあたしが日本の
>
> 一番偉い人になれたら
>
> 即座にヤツをクビにします

(The singer is female, hence あたし)

So far, I can gleam the meaning of the first two lines to be "If I were the most powerful/influential/important person in Japan..." the issue is with the third line. Reasonably, it'd be "I'd immediately fire that guy." But within the context of this song, I really don't think it makes sense.

The lines before it talks about the singers dislike of alarm clocks. As well, when the line "即座にヤツをクビにします" is spoken, it's accompanied by a visual of an alarm clock with an X over it. This makes me think the line is referring to the clock, and ヤツ here is being used to mean "object/thing" rather than person. The only issue it then becomes, however, is that I can't find any meaning for クビにします outside of firing somebody from their job, and that doesn't quite fit...which is why I ask, is there a meaning, perhaps slang, with this word that would mean something along the lines of "destroy" or "get rid of"? Or do I have this all wrong?

[Link to the song I'm referring to](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm33852959), the lyrics I listed appear at 0:30.

Thanks in advance!

edit: the song in the link contains flashing lights in the music video!! Just a heads up!

Comment: So I clicked on the link to watch the video, and I think you should put up a massive CONTAINS FLASHING LIGHTS, MAY INDUCE SEIZURES warning. Seriously XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

クビにする means "to fire someone" as you said. It is rarely used as other meanings.

The sentence before you refer to is 朝一のアラームほど許せない輩はいないでしょ. 輩 is used for a person, not for objects. ヤツ is the same as 輩. So this lyricist regards alarm clocks as humans. That is "personification".

Answer (score 1):

Daijirin (三省堂 スーパー大辞林) lists the meaning of 首にする as:

> (1) 解雇する (to fire someone)
> (2) 首を切る (to behead someone)

Maybe that second one fits better in the song. Then again, maybe it just means that they dislike the alarm clocks so much that they would just fire whoever made them.